# Disable a button in PXWizard

Tags: acumatica

So I'm stuck with this trying to workout how to disable the Next button of a PXWizard. I'd like to only enable it once all entries are valid etc. I know the Next button is tied up to an Action somehow. But even if the Action itself is disabled. The button remains enabled. Hence if I clicked on the Next button then, I get an exception that the button is disabled. Can anyone point me in the right direction ? Unfortunately I couldn't find anything online regarding how to use the PXWizard.

TIA

Comment: PXWizard doesn't exists in documentation so additional details would help understand what you're doing here.

Comment: Wizard consists of pages. Pages contain fields. If a field value doesn't pass a validation e.g. either wrong or non existing value. The Next button must be disabled. Or at least prevent it from changing the page.

Comment: Do you refer to the Acumatica installation wizard?

Comment: I concur, wizard or pxwizard is insufficient to locate the feature you are referring to.

Comment: @ChrisH I'm referring to PXWizard control. An example would be in CR503320 screen - a mass update screen. It will popup a Wizard screen to choose which field(s) are you trying to update. So on this one, the "Next" button should  be disabled. Unless I ticked one of the fields.